# mysql query to find the values based on a given date compare to two date field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this:

```
╔════╦════════════╦══════════╦══════════╦
║ id ║ cinema     ║ from     ║ till     ║           
╠════╬════════════╬══════════╣══════════╣
║  1 ║  cinema1   ║2016-02-20║2016-02-22║
║  2 ║  cinema2   ║2016-02-12║2016-02-29║  
║  3 ║  cinema3   ║2016-02-05║2016-02-19║
║  4 ║  cinema4   ║2016-02-19║2016-02-20║
║  5 ║  cinema5   ║2016-02-21║2016-02-23║
║  6 ║  cinema6   ║2016-02-04║2016-02-18║
╚════╩════════════╩══════════╝══════════╝
```

I want all `cinema` values where a given date (let's say '2016-02-20') is between `from` and `till` or `from` is a date in the future.

In other words, I want this result:

```
╔════════════╗
║   cinema   ║
╠════════════╣
║  cinema1   ║
║  cinema2   ║
║  cinema4   ║
║  cinema5   ║
╚════════════╝
```

For example `from` date of 'cinema5' ('2016-02-21') is greater than '2016-02-20' but as this is a date in the future I need that result, too.

Please help me find me a solution.

Comment: `... WHERE '2016-02-20' BETWEEN from AND till;`. If you also want "Cinema5" in there... not sure what the logic is, but.. you can just toss an `OR` into your `WHERE` clause  `... WHERE '2016-02-20' BETWEEN from AND till OR cinema = 'cinema5'`

Comment: Be careful, you're using a MySQL reserved word here, being `from` and requires special attention. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii- it is for the better understanding of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compare the dates...

```
select cinema 
from table 
where date(`from`) >= '2016-02-20' or date(till) >= '2016-02-20'
```

Comment: that `from` should be ticked `\``. Since it's a MySQL reserved word.

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii- didn't mind that

Comment: You're welcome Michael.

Comment: Thanks Michael For ur answer

Comment: You're welcome @SanoojT